# Using Wine for Windows printer driver on Linux

Tags: wine, printing

We have some old printers with Windows drivers only at my work space. Is there any general way to use their drivers through Wine?

I have not found any decent and new documentation about the problem.

**Edit:**
We have Sharp AR-5516, and according to http://www.openprinting.org/printers there are not any Linux drivers.

Comment: Are you sure that there are no linux drivers? What are those printers?

Comment: Please list the models. If they are HP it should be possible to use them from Ubuntu.

Comment: http://www.witch.westfalen.de/Wine-HOWTO/wineprintconfig.html seems pretty solid

Comment: I doubt you need to go to the trouble. Most printers work fine. Have you actually tried them out?

Comment: @Rinzwind I added the model

Comment: (Since this is being hit anyway) I'd be interested to see if you could use a windows host as a print server which could process the jobs for the linux machines on the network

Comment: @Wilf that most likely works, however currently I don't have this problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you can't use printer drivers designed for Windows on Linux. Wine doesn't help either because it doesn't emulate the hardware interfaces on which *device drivers* rely. (Wine aims to emulate the programming interfaces used by Windows *applications* only.)

If you want to print from an application executed through Wine, the latter still requires a working Linux printer driver since all Wine does is to translate the application’s printing instructions to equivalent instructions understood by Linux’ printing subsystem (which is almost always CUPS these days).